# searching for a program / tool that can show you screenshot how your html page show in big mail servers

Tags: html, email, newsletter

i search for tool / program that i can upload my html (newsletter),
and the program can show me screenshot or in other way

how my newsletter seems in GMAIL / YAHOO / HOTMAIL / OUTLOOK  ..
the big mail servers ,

it saves for me , the need to open an account in every provider.
and check in every mail how it seems .

thanks

Comment: So something like browsershots but for emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://litmusapp.com/

Comment: you know a free software also ?

Comment: No, I don’t. Maybe it costs money to run a service like this?